# How to use batch norm to perform input standardization?

Tags: neural-networks, standardization, batch-normalization

I need to train a model with an un-normalized dataset and I can not directly standardize it (subtract the mean and divide by the std), but I do have the mean and std for each feature. Thus I'm thinking about using the [keras BN layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) to do the normalization automatically, by using it directly after the input layer, freezing its weights for gamma & beta, and replace its running mean and std with my own. However, I have no clue how to change the `moving_mean_initializer` and `moving_variance_initializer` in the keras BN layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set them to what you want using [constant initializers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/Constant).

Example:

```
init_obj = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(
    value=<value>
)
```

And pass this as the parameter value.